# How to solve this differential equation? Circle?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck with the following differential equation:

$ (y+y')^2 = y-y' $

I nearly get the equation of a circle but I have an extra term $2yy'$
So I don't really see how I should parametrize it

Comment: i would write$$y'^2+2yy'+y'-y+y^2=0$$

Comment: Thats what I did, I tried to put the $y'$ and the $y$ together to get the equation of a circle but I'm stuck with the $2yy'$

Comment: i would solve it for $y'$

Comment: Oh, I thought whenever there is no x we had to do a parametrization

Comment: Set $u(x)=e^x(y(x)+\frac12)$ then $$u'^2=2e^xu-\tfrac34e^{2x}.$$ Maybe that can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would see it as a quadratic equation in $y'$ and write
$$y'^2+2yy'+y'-y+y^2=0\\
y'=\frac 12(-(2y+1)\pm \sqrt{8y+1})$$
which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%201%2F(-(2y%2B1)%2Bsqrt(8y%2B1))) is able to integrate to 
$$x=(\log[1 - \sqrt{1 + 8 y}] - 3 \log[3 - \sqrt{1 + 8 y}])/2+c$$
for the plus sign and 
$$=(\log[1 + \sqrt{1 + 8 y}] - 3 \log[3 + \sqrt{1 + 8 y}])/2+c$$
for the minus sign